# How to send data from angular2 (angular4) to nodejs server which save it in mysql

Tags: node.js, angular

I have searched all over the google but was not be able to find any good working example please help me I am new to the Angular2 (angular4).

I want angular2 app to send data to node js server to save the data in mysql database.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What do you mean by nodejs, do you have an up and running server side web application written in nodejs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to interact with any API 
https://angular.io/guide/http